# Visual Studio 2022 winform designer does not show ApplicationSettings in the property window of any control

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In VS 2022 I create a new winform (.net 6.0) project.  I put one textbox on the form.  In the properties window, at the top, I'm used to seeing an item "ApplicationSettings" where I can bind the TEXT property of the textbox to an application setting.  But I no longer see the line for "ApplicationSettings".  If I open an older winform project it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature is (still) not available for WinForms .NET 6 but if you create a WinForms .NET framework project, it's available.

**Data binding to application settings in code**

You can setup the data binding in code:

1. Create or open the Application settings. (Project properties -> Settings -> Create or open application settings.)
2. Add a user-scoped property like `Property1` (if you want it to be modifiable by user in a data-binding scenario.)
3. Setup a databinding in code, like this:

   ```
   this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", 
       Properties.Settings.Default, "Property1", true,
       DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
   ```

**Designer workaround**

If you really want a designer-based solution, then:

1. Create or open the Application settings. (Project properties -> Settings -> Create or open application settings.)
2. Change the application settings class modifier to `public` (on the top bar) to make it visible to the *Add new data source* window.
3. After building the project, in the databinding section of the property grid, for your control, add a new project data source and setup databinding to Settings. (Preferably advanced setting and choosing OnPropertyChanged.)
4. Then you need to set the data source when you load form:

   ```
   settingsBindingSource.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default;
   ```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, for the Visual Studio Community Version:

1. Closed the entire Project/Solution in Visual Studio.
2. Reloading the .sln file in Visual Studio IDE along with the Dependencies.
3. Double Clicking the [image: Form.cs[Design]] (on the highlighted part) opened the Form in the Design format.

Hope this helps!