# Winforms replacement for ApplicationSettings->PropertyBinding in .net 6.0?

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0

In .net 4.6 and before there was a ApplicationSettings->PropertyBinding property setting you could use on common controls and other things which binded a control(ex. textbox) to a settings and it would act as a modifyable application settings.
In net 6.0 this option is gone. Was this moved to some other location in net 6.0 and I cant seem to find it or was it removed and you have to implement your own programmable solution? If so, what is the best way to tackle this as from what I read application settings are read-only, how to then update changes real-time?
[image: functionality in 4.6]

Comment: You can add property bindings in code yourself, there's no real need for a tool, even though it may simplify the process (or, make it more *graphic*). You can use UI in .Net Framework to add a binding, see what it does (it's simple binding) and replicate that code in .Net 5+ -- Settings in the Application scope are a different thing. You bind Settings in the User scope, if these are supposed to be editable (e.g., you bind the Text property of a TextBox instead of the Text property of a Label).

Comment: There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4941) on this topic in WinForms repo. But for now, you can do in in code, as mentioned above. Here is an example: [Visual Studio 2022 winform designer does not show ApplicationSettings in the property window of any control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70553881/3110834)

Comment: If you really want a designer-based solution, then you need to change the application settings class modifier to `public` in the setting designer. Then after building the project, in the databinding section of the property grid for your control, add a new project data source and setup databinding to Settings. Then you need to set the data source when you load form: `settingsBindingSource.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default;`

Comment: Thanks for the answers and links, was already eyeing binding, this just confirms it.