# (ApplicationSettings) not showing on form properties - Visual Studio 2022 C#

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, visual-studio-2022, application-settings

I was looking for a way to create a sort of "global" setting for the background color of some forms in a project. Some examples I found suggested using this (ApplicationSettings) option on Properties, like this (sorry I'm new here so I can't post the image directly):

[image]

The problem is that I looked everywhere and couldn't find that, mine appears like this:

[image]

Is there a way to add that option?

Comment: Right click on your project in solution explorer  -> Properties ->Settings -> General -> Create or open application settings

Comment: @Jakobson, that won't enable you to bind those settings to control properties, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Click on the background of the Form to select it in the properties window. click on a control to select a control.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes, that won't help because the reason it's "missing" is that the OP is targeting .NET Core rather than .NET Framework.

Comment: @John I did not know, so that what I talking about is only related for example to bind some information to global properties, like user password after login, and then retrieving these information after next run time ?

Comment: @Jakobson, you can create settings and use them in .NET Core apps just as you would in .NET Framework apps. The difference is that the WinForms designer doesn't support binding to those settings. You can still bind to them in code though. The WinForms designer had to be rebuilt from scratch for .NET Core and there are a few things that are still missing and some may never be added, if Microsoft don't think they are used enough to warrant the work involved.

Comment: @John thank you sir for clarifying. Definitely good points for a deeper understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022 winform designer does not show ApplicationSettings in the property window of any control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553184/visual-studio-2022-winform-designer-does-not-show-applicationsettings-in-the-pro)

Answer (score 3):

The ability to bind directly to application settings in Windows Forms has not been migrated from the .NET Framework to .NET Core.

However, with some code and a workaround you can still bind to your settings.

1. Right click on you project and navigate to *Properties > Settings > General*. Click on *"Create or open application settings"*.
2. Add your setting, e.g., with *Name = "DefaultBackColor"* and *Type = System.Drawing.Color*.
3. Close the project properties and compile.
4. Visual Studio has created a file *Properties > Settings.settings > Settings.Designer.cs*. Open *Settings.Designer.cs*. You will see an automatically generated `internal sealed partial class Settings` having a property `public Color DefaultBackColor { get; }`. To be able to create a binding source we must make this class `public` and compile again. This class will be re-created later with the `internal` modifier, but we do not mind, as we need the `public` modifier only temporarily.
5. In the Forms designer click on the background of your form to select it in the properties window.
6. In the properties window select *DataBindings > Advanced*. In the *Bindings* combo box select *"Add new Object Data Source..."*, select the `Settings` class and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
7. In my case Visual Studio did not update the Binding drop-down immediately. So, I had to fiddle around a bit, but finally I got the entry *Other Data Sources > Project Data Sources > Properties > Settings > DefaultBackColor*. In the left list select `BackColor` and then select this `DefaultBackColor` in the Binding drop-down. This creates a `settingsBindingSource` on your form and wires up the `BackColor` of your form.
8. Set the data source of this binding source in the constructor of your form:

   ```cs
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       settingsBindingSource.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default;
   }
   ```

Now, the form and all the controls, which inherit the `BackColor` from the form, will have the color defined in the application settings.

In your other forms repeat the steps 7 and 8.

Comment: Such a detailed explanation, thank you!

Comment: Good step by step description. I still don't understand why microsoft has to complicate something that was simple.

Answer (score 2):

That option is available for projects targeting .NET Framework but not for those targeting .NET Core, which includes .NET 5 and later. Windows Forms was not originally supposed to make the trip to .NET Core but Microsoft realised that many people would sooner ignore .NET Core than abandon WinForms. You have a choice to make whether you want that functionality or you want to target .NET Core.

Note that you can probably just write the code yourself to bind a property to an application setting. I just created a binding for the `Text` property of a form and the following code was generated in the designer code file:

```cs
this.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text",
     global::MyWindowsFormsApp.Properties.Settings.Default, "Form1Text", true,
     System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

You can basically write that code yourself in the `Load` event handler, where you would likely bind other properties, e.g. to data retrieved from a database.

Comment: But something like that would solve my problem (add the same background to all forms automatically)?

Comment: @TainaMaia, if you have multiple forms bound to the same setting and you change that setting then those multiple forms will all change to reflect that.